# Custom exception is thrown but the fields are not set, using MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I am testing my endpoints using `MockMvc`. But, I get an error of `No matching constant for [0] at org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf ....`. I know what causes this error.

The error occurs in my exception handler class. `applicationException.getHttpStatusCode()` is `0` that's why, the exception is thrown. That means my `applicationException` fields are not set.(all of them either empty/0 or null)

This is my controller advice for exception handling.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ApplicationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ApplicationException> handleApplicationException(ApplicationException applicationException) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(applicationException, HttpStatus.valueOf(applicationException.getHttpStatusCode()));
    }
}
```

I am getting the error while testing `AppUserController.findAppUserById(UUID)` service.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser(username = "user")
class AppUserControllerTest {


    @MockBean
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @MockBean
    private AppUserService appUserService;

    @MockBean
    private AppUserMapper appUserMapper;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
    void findAppUserById_throwsNotFound() throws Exception {

        //given
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("ac0a1859-8e59-4ede-8def-043c32aa3208");

        //when
        when(userDetailsService.findAppUserById(any())).thenThrow(ResourceNotFoundException.class);
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc
                .perform(get("/app-users/" + uuid))
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
                .andExpect(result -> assertTrue(result.getResolvedException() instanceof ResourceNotFoundException))
                .andReturn();
        String resultContent = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        ResourceNotFoundException response = objectMapper.readValue(resultContent, ResourceNotFoundException.class);

        //then
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals(404, response.getHttpStatusCode());

    }
}
```

**AppUserController**

```
   @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<AppUserResponse> findAppUserById(@PathVariable UUID id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(appUserMapper.appUserToResponse(userDetailsService.findAppUserById(id)), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**AppUserService.findAppUserById()** This service throws `ResourceNotFoundException`. And I am mocking this service with `Mockito` and tell the service to throw exception with this line of code in my `AppUserControllerTest` class.

```
when(userDetailsService.findAppUserById(any())).thenThrow(ResourceNotFoundException.class);
```

```
    public AppUser findAppUserById(UUID id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        AppUser appUser = appUserRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
                () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Kullanıcı bulunamadı")
        );
        if (!appUser.isEnabled()) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException(PASSIVE_USER_MESSAGE);
        }
        return appUser;
    }
```

And this is the `ResoruceNotFoundException` exception, base exception(`ApplicationExcception`).

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"stackTrace", "cause", "suppressed", "localizedMessage"})
public class ApplicationException extends RuntimeException {

    private final int resultCode;
    private final String message;
    private final int httpStatusCode;
    private final ZonedDateTime thrownAt;

    private static final String ZONE_ID = "Europe/Istanbul";

    public ApplicationException(int resultCode, String message, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        super();
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        this.message = message;
        this.httpStatusCode = httpStatus.value();
        this.thrownAt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(ZONE_ID));
    }

 }
```

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends ApplicationException {
    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(-1,message,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

The problem is that, I could throw the exception. I know that because `assertTrue(result.getResolvedException() instanceof ResourceNotFoundException)` is true. However, the fields of `ResourceNotFoundException` are not set. I know that because
[image]

``
Why the `ResourceNotFoundException`'s fields are not set? Any comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the fields initialized, you'll need to create the exception by calling the single-argument constructor you've declared. To do so, you must replace the mocking here:

```
when(userDetailsService.findAppUserById(any()))
    .thenThrow(ResourceNotFoundException.class);
```

and make the mock return an actual object (therefore calling the one-argument constructor):

```
when(userDetailsService.findAppUserById(any()))
    .thenThrow(new ResourceNotFoundException("test err msg"));
```